# How to handle noise reduction in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, audio, package, noise, recording

Using flutter_sound to record audio in flutter application. The recorded audio was not clear, background noise was more. How to remove the noise in mic recording. Is there any packages available / platform code to invoke.

Comment: Did you find any good package for noise reduction while recording?

Comment: Did you find any good package? any luck?